# On seems to be storing variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pulling my hair out with this one. I'm writing a lightweight slider plugin for jQuery (nothing I'm going to release, just to keep things lightweight for this website build).

I'm wanting to be able to update the settings, e.g. when it autoplays and when it doesn't. Seems simple enough, however it appears not.

```
$.fn.slider = function(options) {

    var settings = $.extend({
            autoplay: 4000,
            pause: false
    }, options);

    console.log(settings.pause);

    this.each(function() {

            if(!$(this).data("init")) {

                    var $slider = $(this);
                    var $slide = $(".slide", $slider);
                    var $active = $slide.first().addClass("active");
                    var interval;

                    var animation = function(obj) {
                            $slide.removeClass("active");
                            obj.addClass("active");
                    }

                    var autoplay = function() {
                            interval = setInterval(function() {
                                    $slider.trigger("next");
                            }, settings.autoplay);
                    }
                    autoplay();

                    $slider.on("next", function() {
                            $active = $active.next(".slide").length ? $active.next(".slide") : $slide.first();
                            animation($active);
                    });

                    $slider.on("prev", function() {
                            $active = $active.prev(".slide").length ? $active.prev(".slide") : $slide.last();
                            animation($active);
                    });

                    $slider.on("mouseover", function() {
                            console.log(settings.pause);
                            if(settings.pause) clearInterval(interval);
                    });

                    $slider.on("mouseout", function() {
                            clearInterval(interval);
                            autoplay();
                    });

                    $slider.data("init", true);
            };
    });
}
```

I'm updating the code via `$(".intro [slider]").slider({pause: true});` however, the first console.log is reporting true but the one happening on hover is reporting false?

I don't understand why it's storing the variable.

Comment: It's because on the first call you set `data('init', true)`. Hence the `if(!$(this).data("init")) {` check means that no work will be done on successive calls to the plugin. You need to completely change your logic to make this work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this is what I'm wanting to happen to stop from the binds being bound to the object multiple times. However the variable isn't being updated. I think it's because the variable is bound to the function and in calling it again is creation a new instance. What would be the correct way of updating the setting without reinitialising.

Comment: The normal practice here is to change the method signature to differentiate between instantiating the plugin and changing it's settings. You could do `$().slider({})` to create and `$().slider('options', 'name', 'value')` or `$().slider('options', {})` to set the options. You can then check the `typeof` the first parameter to know what operation is required.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks Rory, any example of this you know of?

Comment: I'm not very good at jQuery are `"next"` and `"prev"` events?

Comment: @zer00ne they are functions which I have bound to the object which can be  later triggered